# Syntax error in python when writing "0." in digits.data

Tags: python, syntax-error

```
>>> from sklearn import datasets
>>> iris = datasets.load_iris()
>>> digits = datasets.load_digits()
>>> print(digits.data)  

[[ 0.   0.   5. ...   0.   0.   0.]
 [ 0.   0.   0. ...  10.   0.   0.]
 [ 0.   0.   0. ...  16.   9.   0.]
 ...
 [ 0.   0.   1. ...   6.   0.   0.]
 [ 0.   0.   2. ...  12.   0.   0.]
 [ 0.   0.  10. ...  12.   1.   0.]]
```

After typing that in, I get the following returned

```
File "<ipython-input-7-14f34e71b8f6>", line 6
    [[ 0.   0.   5. ...   0.   0.   0.]
             ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: Why are you typing the results of print ()?

Answer (score 0):

You must have been copying and pasting this example from somewhere, right?
Only copy, paste and try to run the first part:

```
from sklearn import datasets
iris = datasets.load_iris()
digits = datasets.load_digits()
print(digits.data)
```

The bottom part is the result of the above code:

```
[[ 0.   0.   5. ...   0.   0.   0.]
 [ 0.   0.   0. ...  10.   0.   0.]
 [ 0.   0.   0. ...  16.   9.   0.]
 ...
 [ 0.   0.   1. ...   6.   0.   0.]
 [ 0.   0.   2. ...  12.   0.   0.]
 [ 0.   0.  10. ...  12.   1.   0.]]
```

and does not make sense to be typed.
Let me know if this helps.